# Rails Mysql2::Error: Use of count to get group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-geocoder

I am getting an abrupt error with group and count when I am using near for searching a repairshop near a place. I am using geocoder gem to geocode the repairshops on creation.

Suppose I call the query as:

```
Repairshop.where(:approved => true).group(:title).count
```

I get the right result as hash: `{"my title" => 1}`and everything is fine and dandy.

Now, when I call group on the city or state and then count on the results, I get a Mysql2 error:

Let me show it in steps:

1. Repairshop.where(:approved => true).near('syracuse', 200)

> gives the active record relation with my title repairshop and it works
>   fine in finding with near query.

2. After chaining this with group(:city) I get the same result as shown below:

[image]

3. Now, when I try to chain count on it like:

   Repairshop.where(:approved => true).near('syracuse', 200).group(:city).count

I get the following error shown below:

[image]

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.0481221 -
>   repairshops.latitude) ' at line 1: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT
>   repairshops.*, 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.0481221 -
>   repairshops.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(43.0481221 * PI() /
>   180) * COS(repairshops.latitude * PI() / 180) *
>   POWER(SIN((-76.14742439999999 - repairshops.longitude) * PI() / 180 /
>   2), 2))) AS distance, MOD(CAST((ATAN2( ((repairshops.longitude -
>   -76.14742439999999) / 57.2957795), ((repairshops.latitude - 43.0481221) / 57.2957795)) * 57.2957795) + 360 AS decimal), 360) AS bearing) AS
>   count_repairshops_all_3958_755864232_all_2_all_asin_sqrt_power_sin_43_0481221_repairshops_latitude_all_pi_180_2_2_cos_43_0481221_all_pi_180_all_cos_repairshops_latitude_all_pi_180_all_power_sin_76_14742439999999_repairshops_longitude_all_pi_180_2_2_as_dis,
>   city AS city FROM `repairshops` WHERE `repairshops`.`approved` = 1 AND
>   (repairshops.latitude BETWEEN 40.153486437783044 AND 45.94275776221696
>   AND repairshops.longitude BETWEEN -80.10844293387429 AND
>   -72.1864058661257 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((43.0481221 - repairshops.latitude) * PI() / 180 /
>   2), 2) + COS(43.0481221 * PI() / 180) * COS(repairshops.latitude *
>   PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-76.14742439999999 - repairshops.longitude) *
>   PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 200) GROUP BY
>   `repairshops`.`city` ORDER BY distance ASC

The Repairshop model class looks like this and I have installed the geocoder gem:

```
class Repairshop < ActiveRecord::Base
    geocoded_by :full_address
    after_validation :geocode


end
```

Everything worked perfectly in SQLite but here it gives an error when chained. I am not using MySQL syntax directly so don't understand where is the problem.

Note: I did the MySQL2 setup correctly and using a local server for development. The group(:field).count works fine for other fields unrelated to location

Will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi. near syntax is strange to me. Where does it come from? it appears that we couldn't combine Repairshop.where(:approved => true).near('syracuse', 200) with group syntax. The results "near" returned couldn't be grouped.

Comment: It comes from geocoder gem

Answer (score 1):

The `Geocoder` gem seems to be rewriting the select clause in a way that is incompatible with `#group`. Using sub-selects may be a solution:

```
Repairshop.where(
  id: Repairshop.where(
    :approved => true
  ).near(
    'syracuse', 200
  ).select(:id)
).group(
  :city
).count
```

Comment: Doesn't work with geocoder. pluck neither, but gave me a direction. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Working solution would be to use:

`Repairshop.where(id: repairshop.near(params[:location], params[:radius]).map{|i| i.id})` instead of `Repairshop.near(params[:location], params[:radius])` and then running group and count

But if someone can suggest a better solution. will really appreciate!